# How to maximize Std Dev given a range of possible values, a number of values, and a specific mean?

Tags: statistics, optimization, standard-deviation

(*I'm asking here and not stats.stackexchange because I'd like a mathematical proof of this*)

In this question: [Prove how to maximize Standard Deviation given a certain mean $\bar{x}$ and set of values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838765/prove-how-to-maximize-standard-deviation-given-a-certain-mean-barx-and-set/1838768#1838768); as pointed out by @mathguy in his second paragraph, I assumed that the mean and values were not independent and that the mean was $\frac{a+b}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are the minimum and maximimum values of the range respectively.

**I'd like to understand how to maximize the SD of $n$ values in a range $[a,b]$ for an arbitrary mean $\bar{x}=y$.**

For example, how would you maximize the standard deviation for $5$ values in the range $[0,1]$ with a mean of $0.3$?

Ideally I'd love to have a solution for this specific example (or another) and an understanding for the general solution.

Should we use calc, and if so how? Can we use something else?

Comment: Just to avoid repeating the mistake you cite, when you write "$5$ values in the range $[0,1]$ with a mean of $0.3$", do you mean that the five values actually have that mean, or that the standard deviation is calculated *as if* the mean were $0.3$, regardless of the mean of the five values?

Comment: @EricTowers, yes the 5 values have mean 0.3. I want to constrain the mean of those values and then try to max out the SD.

Comment: Why do you have deleted your question ?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844839/confusion-about-independence-and-number-of-trials-in-conditional-probability

Comment: @callculus, I thought it might be too long and confusing for people to read through and answer, so I figured I would just think about it more but I'm still stuck on it, hah. EDIT: I apologize if you were writing an answer when I deleted. I assumed the system would warn me if that was the case. (please let me know and I can put it back up if you were writing something)

Comment: Jeremy, it is not necessary that you re-activate your question. I was just interested in the reason of the deletion. That´s why I appreciate your reply. Thanks for that. I hope you find an explanation for yourself. If not I´m looking forward to your (modified) question.

Comment: @callculus, Thank you. I will think about it more and try to extract better the essence of my confusion before posting again if I can't figure it out soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximising the standard deviation or variance for a given mean is equivalent to maximising the sum of squares of the values for a given sum of the values.

Meanwhile if $b \ge a$ and $\delta \gt 0$, $$(a-\delta)^2 +(b+\delta)^2 $$ $$= a^2-2a\delta+\delta^2+b^2+2b\delta + \delta^2 $$ $$= a^2+b^2 +2(b-a)\delta+2\delta^2  $$ $$\gt a^2+b^2$$

so the sum of squares is maximised if and only if as many terms as possible are as large as possible, even if this makes others smaller.

In your example of five terms in $[0,1]$ with a mean of $0.3$

- this make the sum of the terms $5\times 0.3=1.5$
- we can make one term as large as possible in the interval, namely $1$, leaving $0.5$ for the sum of the other terms
- then we can make a second term as large as possible in the remaining sum, namely $0.5$, leaving $0$ for the sum of the remaining other terms
- so the remaining terms are $0$

and the standard deviation is maximised with values of $\{1,0.5,0,0,0\}$

Comment: Thank you, it's great to know there's a way to do this without calc. Just to make sure, is $\delta$ in your general formula the mean? If so, why is the second term $b+ \delta$ and  not $b- \delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ is an arbitrary small positive increase to the larger value and corresponding decrease to the smaller value so that their sum remains the same.  If such a $\delta$ exists, you can increase the sum of squares and so the standard deviation without changing the mean, so the maximum occurs when there is no such $\delta$, i.e. when as many terms as possible are as large as possible even if this makes others smaller

Comment: Thank you, everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

First, you might as well assume that the mean is zero, so that $a < 0 < b$; that just simplifies things. (Otherwise: let $a' = a - \mu; b' = b - \mu$ and you can convert your problem for $[a, b], \mu$ to mine for $[a, b], 0$ by subtracting $\mu$ from all the sample values, etc.)

The SD is 
$$
s = \sum x_i^2
$$
and you want to maximize this subject to 
$$
\sum x_i = 0.
$$
That's a classic constrained optimization, which you can solve using lagrange multipliers and a little more.

The gradient of the target, $s$, is 
$$
\nabla s = (2x_1, 2x_2, \ldots, 2x_n)
$$
while the gradient of the constraint is 
$$
\nabla c = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)
$$
At the optimum, your variables must satisfy the constraint, and must have
$$
\nabla c = \lambda \nabla s
$$
for some real value $\lambda$. That means that all variables will have the same value, and hence that value must be zero. The target is optimized when the values are all zero. Unfortunately, this optimum is a min rather than a max. :(

Now on to the "a little more": if the constraint doesn't occur in the interior of the domain at a point where lagrange multipliers find it, it must happen on the boundary, where some $x_i$ is either $a$ or $b$.

If you look at the two-variable case, and let $q = \min{|a|, |b|}$, you find that $x_1 = b$ leads to $x_2 = -b$, and if $|b| > |a|$, this is not valid. So the solution is either $x_1 = q, x_2 = -q$, or its negative.

(In fact, for any solution, you can permute the $x_i$ and get another solution, or any of the $x_i$s to get other solutions. So I'm just going to find *one* optimum, not all of them.)

For the three-variable case, let's simplify things a little and assume that $|a| \le |b|$ (or else rename them). Then picking $x_1$ as a variable that must have a boundary value, there are cases $x_1 = a$ and $x_1 = b$. If $x_1 = b$, then $x_2 + x_3 = -b$.

If $|a| < |b|/2$, this has no solutions. 
Otherwise, we have the same optimization problem as before, for the two-variable case, but with the "mean" constrained to be $-b$. Hmmm.

There's another possibility, which is that $x_1 = a$, and then $x_2 + x_3 = -a$, and again we're reduced to a smaller problem.

This just begs for a recurrence relation. Let's define

$$
M(a, b, \mu, n)
$$
to be the max of $\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2$, subject to $\sum x_i = \mu$, and $a \le x_i \le b$ for all $i$. 
$$
P(a, b, \mu, n)
$$
to be the point $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ at which this is achieved,  with $x_1 = a$ or $x_1 = b$.

[...and I stopped work here...]

If you look closely, you can see that my answer is headed (albeit very slowly) towards the same place as @Henry's more pithy and to-the-point answer, so I'm going to stop work, but leave the answer here as a guide for others who might be asking similar questions.

Comment: So there's no way to do it without calculus, right?

Comment: I have no idea, having not examined all of mathematics for a solution.:) But I know that there's a way to do it *with* calc, which is what I'm describing. Maybe when I'm done, we'll see that the solution is intuitively obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and sorry if I sounded ungrateful, I could've expressed my question better. I took multivariable a while ago but didn't have strong enough intuition back then to really understand it. I think now it should make a lot more sense :)

Comment: You do not need calculus or Lagrangian methods

Comment: @JohnHughes: Don't delete your answer: it provides a more general method than mine

Comment: @JohnHughes, yes please don't delete, I will accept his answer which I really like too. I was debating it, feeling bad for unaccepting yours but knowing that you agree makes it easier.
I think it's always good to have as many approaches/intuitions as possible for a single problem.